# The stationary distribution of a rook's random walk

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, random-walk, simulation, chessboard

Let us consider a classic $8\times 8$ chessboard (grid), where a lone rook is doing a random walk. We assume that the rook starts its journey from the $(7, 0)$ square ($A1$), and that there are no other pieces on the board that could "block" the rook's movements.

We know that the rook's graph is a perfect graph, and thus the number of available moves at any square of the chessboard for the rook will be 14. I want to infer the stationary distribution of the Markov chain that corresponds to the rook's walk.

My initial assumption was that the distribution must be close to a two-dimensional discrete uniform distribution (something like $U_2\{0, 7\}$), i.e. the limiting probability for the rook to occur at any square of the board will be about $1/64$. I tried doing a simulation for the process in python, and what I've obtained did not really match my expectations. The following image represents the stationary distribution that results from the simulation (the color scheme is "viridis", the brighter the color is, the higher the probability. The sum of all limiting probabilities is $1$):

[image: Stationary distribution of the MC corresponding to the random walk of a rook]

For some reason it doesn't seem to follow the uniformness that I was expecting. The code that I wrote for sure does work as intended, since I've also tested it on deriving the stationary distribution for the knight's random walk, and I got the very same result as in [here](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Eyibi/teaching/stat317/2021/Lectures/Lecture6.pdf). So the issue seems to not be code-related.

If anyone helps me to identify the issue in my logic and probably to navigate me in constructing the stationary distribution for the rook's MC, I'll be very grateful!

Thank you in advance!

P.S. One can find the code that I wrote [here](https://pastebin.com/HLtC5GTY).

Comment: "The following image represents the stationary distribution that results from the simulation" How should we interpret this image without any knowledge of what the color coding means or what is displayed in the figure?! Also there is an issue with the link at the end.

Comment: I used viridis color scheme for color coding here, basically, the brighter the color of a cell is, the higher the limiting probability of the rook to occur at the respective square is. If the probabilities were drawn from the uniform distribution, all the squares on the chessboard would have the same color. And, about the link, seems like I made a small mistake in it, thank you for noting! Will edit it shortly

Comment: I edited the link, now it should be openable.

Comment: Can you share you code so we can check it as well?

Comment: I will share the link to my code in about half an hour, as I get back home

Comment: I think the problem is probably with your code. I did a simulation and the limiting distribution is the uniform.

Comment: I have just added a link to the code, put it on Pastebin

Comment: Oh, I have just checked the numerical values in the generated distribution without plotting it, and it seems like the issue is not with the code, but with `matplotlib`, as all the values are actually same and are $1/64$.. My bad :)

Comment: After I set `vmin=0` and `vmax=0.2` keywords for `plt.imshow`, the plot seems to be uniform without any strange deviations